# IIS Host different urls on another server

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have a Asp.net MVC web app, and it has a bunch of controllers with a bunch of urls. I would like to redirect certain urls, for example,  http://example.com/classes/students where any url that has **/classes/** would redirect to another server.

That other server would simple take the load for those requests. Everything else would stay on the primary server. Is there a way to do this? Is this stupid?

I thought about a webfarm, but you need basically 3 servers to do that, and then I would need a backplate for Signarl, because that url uses a pool of connections for chat.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full picture of what you're trying to do, so it would be hard to say whether this is a good idea or not.

That said, you could easily pull this off by using the HTTP Redirect module in IIS on the 'classes' Virtual Directory.